# How to type right to left in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Im typing an Indo Aryan language which is written right to left, but I couldn't find a way to type it correctly in Illustrator. The Language under Character does not work. The Adobe Single-Line and Every-Line Composers also does not work.

How can I type right to left in Illustrator?

Comment: There are hundreds of Indo-Aryan languages (most of which are written left-to-right); could you be more specific about which one you’re trying to write?

Answer (score 7):

In AI 2019:

1. Go to Window > Type > Paragraph Style
2. Open Options > Open Paragraph Style Options
3. Open Middle East Character Formats.
4. Change Direction: Right to Left.
5. Click Ok

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to check Preferences/Type:
[image]

Second, check Paragraph options:
[image]

And last – pick your Arabic font and change system language to Arabic.

Comment: OK, but RtL fails with punctioation while typing in Arabic even after following thoses steps. it's mandatory to install English Supporting Arabic version.

Comment: I confirm this works for Hebrew text. תודה רבה

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps:

1. Go to Edit->Prefrences->Type
2. In 'Language Options' section, click on 'Show Indic Options'
3. Press OK
4. Restart your Adobe Illustrator
5. Go to Window->Type->Paragraph
6. On the top right-hand side of the opened window, next to the arrow sign, click on the menu sign and select 'Middle Eastern & South Asian Every-Line Composer'

You are good to go now.